# only include some keys from {...props}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

here's a first world problem.. I might be asking for something impossible, but I decided to at least ask the question.

I have a react component like this:

```
function TextInput(props) {
  return <input type="text" {...props} />;
}
```

But I don't want people to pass in unexpected values in props because that could break the input. Testing is obviously harder this way too.

So I refactored it to this. Lets say I only want to allow `name`, `value`, and `placeholder`.

```
function TextInput({value, name, placeholder}) {
  const inputProps = {value, name, placeholder};

  return <input type="text" {...inputProps} />;
}
```

However I think this looks strange and unnecessarily duplicated, right?

**Question:** Is there a shorter/better way to keep the spread `{...inputProps}`, but **only** include the values I specified, without repeating the keys twice? And without adding more "lines" of code.

---

**Why do I want this?**

I know this is pedantic and I could do it in 2 lines and some repeating, but I'm trying to find a short, good pattern that I can reuse in both smaller and bigger components.

**Why do I want the spread?** Because it makes it so much more readable than listing all props and maybe even having to add line breaks inside the element when there are too many props. This is more notable with inner children though, like this:

```
<div 
  foo="bar" 
  bar={foo} 
  z={y} 
>
  innerChildContent
</div>
```

I think it's just so much easier to read if I can keep the keys to javascript objects or something similar.

Comment: Notice that object spread syntax isn't in ES6 anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** It looks like `{value, name, placeholder}` doesn't work on its own. You need to embed it inside a spread as well. I was wondering if this was the case when I posted my answer originally, but thought I might be able to get away with the shortcut. Credit to [Bram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835239/7256039) for being first to point out the problem.

```js
function TextInput({value, name, placeholder}) {
  return <input type="text" {...{value, name, placeholder}} />;
}
```

Comment: It seems like that gave a syntax error. Does it work for you @gyre? Im not too used to all the syntax options you have for jsx yet.

Comment: @AndreasNilsson Should be fixed now. I guess my shortcut didn't work after all!

Answer (score 0):

To get the solution of [gyre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823199/7679529) working, you will have to wrap the parameters again into an object before you can use the object spread.

```
function TextInput({value, name, placeholder}) {
  return <input type="text" { ...{value, name, placeholder} } />;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpENag?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

this is why some people use react + typescript.
In my case i setup input props in interface:

```
interface IUserSideBarProps {
    usersData: {
        FullName: string;
        Login: string;
        [propName: string]: any;
    }[];
    options: ISideBarOptions;
    currentUserLogin: string;
}

export class UserSideBar extends React.Component<IUserSideBarProps, undefined> {
```

but i don't know will it be same in plain javaScript